# Product get Small image from collection

Tags: xml, product-collection, product-images

i have tried a lot to get only small image from product collection of product object to create custom XML feed for my products.

but could not able to get succeed yet.

```
  $imgname = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'small_image',$product->getSmallImage())->resize(200, 115);
```

But Result is

```
http://domainname.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/200x115/74bba6f65adf875ca0644363d646988a/images/catalog/product/placeholder/small_image.jpg
```

And my collection is

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                 ->addStoreFilter($this->_storeId)                 
                 ->addAttributeToFilter(
                       'status', array('eq' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED)
                  );
```

it would be great if some one point me in right direction.

Comment: as tried lot of small image using helper funtion.It protected prevent the create small image.. for memory limit

Comment: is there any other which we can grab this ?

Comment: no.only solution to create resize  image of small_image using varien_image

Comment: shall we get small_image from base image url if we have ? without load product object.

Comment: no. base image  will be occur.... Issue with resize image. you can small image directly using below  getSmallImageUrl()

Comment: I just answered to [this question at StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60860444/529403).

Answer (score -1):

Try to use catalog output helper

```
$_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
$imgname = $_helper->init($product,
'small_image',$product->getSmallImage())->resize(200, 115);
```

Comment: You may wanted to refer to catalog/image helper, as there's no init method in catalog/output helper.